# Eclipse Android Graphical Layout Editor Broken

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

I'm running Eclipse Helios on Mac and just updated to ADT 9.0.0.
It seems to have broken the Layout editor.
Any time I try to open a layout xml file with the layout editor I get an error.
The editor has a "missing theme" message while the main error generated is as follows.

```
 Selecting page '0' in AndroidXmlEditor failed    

java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditor.pageChange(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.setActivePage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:1067)
at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.setActivePage(FormEditor.java:607)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.selectDefaultPage(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.addPages(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.createPages(FormEditor.java:138)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:348)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(EditorReference.java:289)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2863)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2768)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2760)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2711)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2707)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2691)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2682)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:651)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:610)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:365)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:208)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:274)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:250)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerActionGroup.handleOpen(PackageExplorerActionGroup.java:373)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$4.open(PackageExplorerPart.java:526)
at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:845)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:843)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1131)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1235)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:264)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:258)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:298)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:3776)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1367)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1390)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1375)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1187)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3622)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3277)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)

Session data
 eclipse.buildId=M20100909-0800 java.version=1.6.0_22 java.vendor=Apple Inc.BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/test/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -keyring /Users/test/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
```

I even tried reinstalling Eclipse and Android plugins but to no avail. Not found anything on the web either I'm afraid.
Anyone else have the same problem or any suggestions?

tim

Comment: Turns out this is not just a Mac problem. Same issue happened on my linux box.

Comment: There is still the problem when I open a layout xml file for the first time and then click on the "Graphical Layout" tab. It never shows up automatically. You still need to swap between two version of Android in the dropdown box (below the 'Create' button) to get the GUI to appear. Quite irritating.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I just stumbled across this same issue now. There seems to be a new dropdown in the "config" section for selecting a platform version (none was selected in my case). Selecting any (eg. "Android 2.2") made the Theme selector appear, and the layout works agin.

Comment: Cheers zmalltalker. That sorted it. For others, just to clarify, the drop down menu is in the layout editor, underneath the "create" button.

Comment: is this really the only fix for this? i can't even select this dropdown menu until i open, close, and re-open the XML file... because of the NPE exceptions

Comment: Whoa.. rather obvious once you know it. But couldn't figure it out myself.. Thx.

Comment: I do still have the open, close, and re-open issue when looking at layouts.. kinda silly.

Comment: I have this problem when I want to use the Google APIs as target. I need to use maps so... or maps or graphical layout... right?

Comment: In case you can't select any below the create button, Install SDK Platform Android 2.1, API7

Answer (score 3):

Same here, but I found something. The problem happen when I try to use 
Google APIs as the Project Build Target.
If I change to Android 2.3, it works as expected

Comment: that is true... any advance on this?

Answer (score 2):

Facing a similar error. I cant see any graphical layout preview in the Graphical Layout tab of mine. Most of the drop down menus are blocked (grayed out). This happens when I target Google APIs 2.3.1 with API level 9. But on the other hand when i build it with Android 2.3.1 API 9, everything works fine.

Comment: I have api level 8 and 9 installed. I often have to swap between two to get the actual GUI editor to show up.

Comment: In my eclipse I can not see the graphical layout tab after setting the new Eclipse and Android enviorment. I can see only the source and design tab. How to see the graphical layout ??

Answer (score 1):

I think its because of the custom layout components ur using.

I think there is a bug already filed for it. You can file another one or vote for existing one to be fixed on priority

Comment: I don't think its anything to do with my layout because even when i create a new empty (linear) layout file I get the same error. Can you give me the url for the bug report please. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with ADT version 15.0.0. After updating ADT to 15.0.1 everything is working fine. Hope this will solve yours issue also.

Answer (score 1):

In the menubar goto **Project>Clean** Select "Clean all projects" and then load the xml again choose your version of android.

This should do. If not try selecting other options.

Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

ADT 11 was released 06 June 2011.

Install the plugin from this link.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

I think it works like the way we expected..

Comment: Please don't post exactly the same answer to multiple questions in quick succession.  If they're duplicate questions, just flag them for closing/merging.