# Android eclipse problem

Tags: android, eclipse

I am facing some unusual problem every now and then to solve I even formatted my system but all in vain, problem is when ever I open any xml file its says **Missing theme** and no graphical layout is rendered as in below image

[image]

Comment: Strange! which OS you're on!?

Comment: Possible duplicate of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050443/android-development-missing-theme-error-in-eclipse-ide-for-layout-xml-files The solution there works. Try that!

Comment: @TheCottonSilk Although I dont get any exception but solution to that question solved my problem Thanks

Comment: @Saurabh Agnihotri: Great that the issue is resolved. You need to look at the logcat output for exception details.

Comment: Glad to have found that you got it working. learned one more thing about Android and Eclipse! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate: [Eclipse Android Graphical Layout Editor Broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811564/eclipse-android-graphical-layout-editor-broken)

Edit: The solution in the above link says you need to select something from the dropdown just below the 'Create' button...

Comment: no its not duplicate of that I get no exceptions as stated in that question

Comment: Did you look at the solution?

Comment: yeah thanks to you too earliear I didnt understand the answer

Comment: No worries. Glad it's working! (I had the same trouble a couple of weeks ago after upgrading my PC!)