# No Graphical layout editor in Android

Tags: android, layout, editor

I imported an Android project in Eclipse. Somehow, the layout editor does not open automatically when I open a layout! After I open it, it gives me the 'Graphical Layout' tab but it is still an empty frame! The only difference I see from my previuos projects is that the top drop-down menu has an option called "Locale" while the older ones had "Any locale".

Please advise.

Comment: you can also try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708574/how-to-get-the-graphical-layout-window-back-in-eclipse-for-android-application-d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something similar happened to me today and I found that if I closed the window/tab and opened again a few times it fixed itself. It was annoying though. Also try going into the xml tab and edit something in there and go back to the Graphical Layout.

Something [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4811564/516286) happened to me a few versions of ADT for eclipse ago.

**EDIT** 
Ok it has just happened to me once again. What I did to resolve was to change the Android version to something else. It's the drop down box beside the `Create...` button. That made it reappear

Comment: Do you have any data to display? For instance, a TextView with no @string or quoted text doesn't display anything.

Comment: @Tim, I tried your suggestion. Altough, I got the panel on the left with form widgets and other components, I do not see the layout screen to it's right! I have a creamed colored frame at the bottom in the panel that says "No XML content. Please add a root view or layout to your document."

Comment: Try this.. Go into the xml view.. clear everything.. save.. go to the graphical layout.... go back to the xml tab.. paste in this `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>`  .. save.. and go back to the graphical layout

Comment: Not sure why but this made it work! I'm at a loss as to what happened here!

Comment: The suggestion by Tim above worked for me. Basically cutting everything from XML view, switch to graphical view, back to xml view and paste everything back.  Absolutely absurd that with ADT version 20 we still have to go through this nonsense.

Answer (score 4):

Restart eclipse. I always close eclipse when this error happens and restarting it after that and my problem got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, it goes away if I switch to XML view and make a single edit, and then save.  Then switch back to graphical layout and the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't working for me no matter what I did. But it started working again when I deleted a bunch of projects in my workspace. My theme for eclipse was also deleted when I did this too, I'm not sure why.